# Application Cache for Dynamic Sites

Tags: php, ios, html, cordova, application-cache

I am making a php mysql web app, my idea is to install in the customer home a web server so they can connect with whatever device they want, probably most of the time they will be using an ipad to connect to the app.

Sometimes the client needs to take out the app with them in the ipad, so after discarding other options(like phonegapp because i need to mantain a mysql db for some functions)i realized that Application Cache may be a good solution: They can use the application with the web server(using db functions like randomize the content, generate Statistics)and when they are offline they can access a local copy of the content, with limited function but working.

The problems that i have is that the site have images,video and audio so at least there are 20mb to cache, i read that with application cache you can only store 5mb and the other problem is that my content is dynamic so i cant add all the files that i need to the cache manifest. I want something like make a wget of the site(save an static html file) and to use the dynamic content when online. I dont know if i can make something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the cache.manifest for the ipad can store more than 5mb.

the currently ios limit is 50mb.

if you cache more files, automatically the ipad ask if you want increase the storeage to 50mb.

take a look at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

it explains you how to create and implement the cache.manifest. its a great tutorial

hope this help.

Comment: I get it working with this http://www.sitesketch101.com/creating-a-dynamic-html5-cache-manifest/ , so now i have a php file for generate the application cache manifest, can be this a good aproach to my needs?is stable to use 100mb cache in an ipad and refresh it daily?is there any point to think about using localStorage too?Thanks